# need help web3.js to read return value of smart contract

Tags: web3js

I need help to locate web3.js function that can send parameters to an existing smart contract function that changes the state of the blockchain. In the smart contract function I am returning a return value which I need to capture using web3.js

For example the below node file calls web3.eth.sendRawTransaction, but when it returns, it gets only the transaction hash and not the return value of the function "addfund".

Using the transaction hash I can see details about the transaction like the block number etc, however, the return value of addfund is not captured anywhere. Is there a way to achieve this ? I know that I can use

```
contract.methods.totalSupply().call((err, result) => { console.log(result) })
```

function to get the return values, but those methods are NOT state changing functions so it is not applicable in my case

My File.js:

```
var contractAddress = '0x17a8fd94665bd5f73e7fede9c69f64959cefd8df';
   var txOptions = {
   nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
   gasLimit: web3.toHex(800000),
   gasPrice: web3.toHex(20000000000),
   to: '0x17a8fd94665bd5f73e7fede9c69f64959cefd8df'
  };
 var rawTx = txutils.functionTx(interfaceABI, 'addfund', 
  ['0xc66ed658f1e75c21df3e50890e983fda34b6052e',100], txOptions);

function sendRaw(rawTx) {
   var privateKey = new Buffer(key, 'hex');
   var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
   console.log('transaction '+ JSON.stringify (transaction));
   transaction.sign(privateKey);
   var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
   console.log('serializedTx ' +serializedTx);
   web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(
   '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('error is' + err);
      } else {
        console.log('result is ' + result);
    }
   });
  }`
  sendRaw(rawTx);
```

Solidity function :

```
function addfund(address sender, uint value ) payable public {

    if (partifunded[msg.sender] == true) {
            for ( uint i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
                    if (participants[i].partaddr == msg.sender)
                     {
                            participants[i].amount += msg.value;
                            totalamountcol = address(this).balance;
                     }
            }
    }
    else
    {
            partifunded[msg.sender] = true;
            participants.push(Participant(msg.value,msg.sender));
            numberofparti = numberofparti+1;
            totalamountcol = address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

Beyond that: Is there a boilerplate code available for capturing events in web3.js that are fired by smart contracts ?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But I suggest you drop that second question: you should ask one question per question, not multiple.